# How to space between content and sidebar widget in blogger?

Tags: html, css, templates, customization, blogger

i want to add some space between main content and sidebar,in black space,there must display backgroung image,i don't want to add border.

see my blog template screenshot.
image link:-https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxpfV.jpg

so,there is no any blank space between main content to sidebar.

See this another screenshot,in this photo you will see some space between main content and sidebar.
image link-https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5bld.jpg

So i want add space like this,anybody know how to do that with margin and padding?

I am using simple white blogger template, so in which class or id,i need to add css code?

thank you very much for any type of help.

Comment: Could you please share your blog url?

Comment: readtoparticles.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

Html code:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="left">
        <p>The left-hand content</p>

    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <p>The right-hand content</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

and Here is the css :

```
#wrapper
{position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
display: block;
width: 100%;
background-color: #ffa;
    }

#right {position: absolute;
border-radius: 5px 10px / 10px;
    top:5%;
    right: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 17%; 
display: block;
background-color: #ccc;
overflow: auto;
    }

#left   {width: 60%; height:100%; 
border-radius: 5px 10px / 10px;
margin-top:2.5%;    
margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 16%; 
display: block;
background-color: #0ff;
overflow: auto;
    }

p   {display: block;
margin: 0.5em;
padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    }
```

The above code will look like this image
http://i57.tinypic.com/29wv614.png

Comment: this is also not work with blogger template,checkout my blogger template codes- http://pastebay.net/1449896